# How can get Network ID of a subnet mask?

Tags: vb.net

This is my code, I can get IP Address and Subnet mask,

```
Dim strHostName As String
Dim strIPAddress As String
Dim strMsg = ""
strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()
strIPAddress = "" ' System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(strHostName).AddressList(0).ToString()
Dim iphe As System.Net.IPHostEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName)

For Each ipheal As System.Net.IPAddress In iphe.AddressList
    If ipheal.AddressFamily = System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork Then
        strIPAddress = ipheal.ToString()

        For Each adapter As Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface In Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
            For Each unicastIPAddressInformation As Net.NetworkInformation.UnicastIPAddressInformation In adapter.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses
                If unicastIPAddressInformation.Address.AddressFamily = Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork Then
                    If strIPAddress.Equals(unicastIPAddressInformation.Address.ToString ) Then
                        'Subnet Mask
                        Dim submark = unicastIPAddressInformation.IPv4Mask.ToString()    
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

I am getting value IP Address=144.28.16.17 and Subnet mask=255.255.240.0

How can I get the Network ID as shown in the image?

[image]

Comment: `ip_address And subnet_mask`?

Comment: Yes, Have function to get network id?

Comment: `network_id = ip_address And subnet_mask`?

Comment: yes. that is right.

Comment: What is your question then?

Comment: Have a function to get value network id?

Comment: Or How can "And" 2 numbers 144 vs 255 in vb.net?

Comment: `144 And 255`?.

Comment: Yes, And binary the same image.

Comment: `144 And 255`?..

Comment: Yes, thank you. it is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For IPv4 convert ip to nums AND then num to ip.  Like this

```
    Dim ip As Net.IPAddress
    Dim mask As Net.IPAddress
    Dim netID As Net.IPAddress

    Dim strIP As String = "144.28.29.17"
    Dim strMask As String = "255.255.240.0"

    If Net.IPAddress.TryParse(strIP, ip) Then
        If Net.IPAddress.TryParse(strMask, mask) Then
            Dim inum As Integer = BitConverter.ToInt32(ip.GetAddressBytes, 0)
            Dim mnum As Integer = BitConverter.ToInt32(mask.GetAddressBytes, 0)
            inum = inum And mnum
            netID = New Net.IPAddress(BitConverter.GetBytes(inum))
        End If
    End If
```